# Direct Form 2 IIR filter input values

Tags: filters, filter-design

In the filter graph below:

[image]

- where circle with 'X' inside is a multiplication
- circle with 'Σ' inside addition
- and the triangle is a delay element

What could be the values x(k) in this type of filter? There is a rule? There is a range? I can understand the matrix of coefficients but i don't know about the x(k) values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x[k]$ is the input signal to the filter; it could be anything. There is no "rule" for what signal you can input to a linear filter. With that said, the stability of filters is usually talked about in a [bounded-in, bounded-out (BIBO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability) sense. If the input signal is unbounded, then it's likely that the output signal will be also. So if anything, the "rule" that you're looking for would be to only apply signals $x[k]$ whose magnitude $|x[k]|$ is bounded below some value $B < \infty$.

Comment: I know this is being very picky but in principle it should be $|x[k]|$ instead of just $x[k]$. Not only does that take into account negative values but also complex valued inputs.